# Using JavaScript, how can I increment all items in an array and return the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, increment

There is one function that I am stuck on with incrementing all of the items in my array and returning the array. What to do now?

```
function incrementByOne(arr) {
  // arr is an array of integers(numbers), Increment all items in the array by
  // return the array
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i] += 1;
    return(arr);
  }
 
}
```

Comment: move the `return` after the loop.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use [Array.prototype.map](http://Ahttps://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with an arrow function for this:

```js
function incrementByOne(arr) {
    return arr.map(value => value + 1);
}

console.log(incrementByOne([1,5,4,7,3]));
```

Your attempt was great, but your `return arr;` is too early. Mind that you're also modifying the array, instead of returning a copy with updated values. You could copy the array first with `arr = [...arr];`.

Answer (score -1):

All I had to do was move the `return` outside the loop.

```
function incrementByOne(arr) {
      // arr is an array of integers(numbers), Increment all items in the array by
      // return the array
      for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i] += 1;
      }
      return(arr);
    }
```